# Number theory in the quadratic field with golden section unit

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, golden-ratio, legendre-symbol

I would like to ask a favor. Does anyone of you here have an access to the book 'Number theory in the quadratic field with golden section unit' by Fred Wayne Dodd? I just need to see Theorem 8.5 of the book which is cited on the article I am reading at the moment. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Too bad [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=37-7AAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22theorem+8.5%22) does not show the complete statement.

Comment: But you can again search there with the key words from the previous search to extend it.

Answer (score 0):

This book is available on Archive.org as an immediate/online rental, FWIW.

https://archive.org/details/numbertheoryinqu0000dodd/page/44/mode/2up